# What does the assert fido.methods.size > 0 mean in the ruby code?

Tags: ruby, methods

I'm starting to learn some ruby now and am doing Ruby Koans exercises. Then I'm stuck in the code:

```
def test_objects_have_methods
    fido = Dog.new
    assert fido.methods.size > 0 
  end
```

I'm confused about `fido.methods`. What does it refer to?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns an array of all the callable methods on the instance `fido`.

I haven't used it in production but it can be quite nice for debugging or when writing weird scripts.

Comment: Thank you! But in this case, `fido` doesn't have any methods, so the size is 0? But the code says the size is bigger than 0?

Comment: Sorry, can I ask you one more question? What is `:fidos_wag` in the code `def fido.wag   :fidos_wag   end`? Is it an attribute? or something else?

Comment: fido is an instance of the class dog. The class `Dog` inherits from `Object` which gives it a quite large number of default methods. like `nil?`, `is_a?`, `object_id` and stuff like that. So the size will never be 0.

Comment: The `:fido_wag` is a symbol http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is a good documentation on everything. [`Object#methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Object.html#method-i-methods):

> Returns a list of the names of public and protected methods of *obj*. This will include all the methods accessible in obj's ancestors. If the optional parameter is `false`, it returns an array of obj's *public* and *protected* singleton methods, the array will not include methods in modules included in obj.

Since you are calling it on `Dog` instance, that apparently is derived from `Object`, the list of methods includes all those, defined on `Object`.